# How to get Ages by IDs in R?

Tags: r

Data

```
ID,Age,Gender
100,69,male
101,75,female
102,84,female
103,,male
104,66,female
```

Code

```
DF <- read.csv("/home/masi/data.csv", header = T)
ids <- c(101,103)
ages <- DF[which(ids), ]$Age
```

Output

```
Error in which(ids) : argument to 'which' is not logical
Calls: makeMatrixPlot -> [ -> [.data.frame -> which
Execution halted
```

You can do `DF[which(gender, ]$ID` but why not for `Age`.

### Other proposals

```
% http://stackoverflow.com/q/40365526/54964
DF[DF$ID %in% ids,"Age"]

with(DF[DF$ID %in% ids,],Age)
```

OS: Debian 8.5
R: 3.1.1

Comment: I challenge the claim that `DF[which(gender, ]$ID` is even valid R code much less helpful in understanding intent. Post tested code. The English language surrounding this question is insufficient to resolve the lack of clarity.

Comment: Downvote for failing to respond constructively to the challenge. The arguments to `which` are supposed to be logical ... not numeric. It was insulting to the audience of potential respondents to copy this data into another question when it was obvious they had nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subsetting with `which()` like this is not a good idea. Use the `subset()` function with the `%in%` operator to test for membership in a vector.

```
ages <- subset(DF, ID %in% ids)$Age
```

or use the `match` function for subsetting

```
ages <- DF[match(ids, DF$ID),"Age"]
```

Comment: Which of these can you use inside functions? Roland says that subset should not be used inside functions, but only for interactive use.

Comment: Why wouldn't this work in a function? As long as you aren't trying to dynamically change fields or comparisons in the condition, it should be fine.

Comment: Maybe, related here http://stackoverflow.com/q/41206377/54964 I am thinking to do the first one without `subset`. - - I got a recommendation not to use `subset` at all in functions.

Comment: That sounds like a silly recommendation. There at something's subset is good for and some it is not. There no reason to avoid it completely.