# Why this R dplyr getAges fails on ordered list?

Tags: r, debian, dplyr

I am thinking to get a list of ages by a list of ids by the following function `getAges`. 
It fails on the whole code example, see the following complete code, by returning ages in wrong order on the given id list.
The code `DF[DF$ID %in% ids,]` takes the whole data (`DF`), considers ids (`DF$ID`), the former in the list of ids (`- - %in% ids`), and returns age of those ids (`[wantedIds]$Age`). 
I am unsure about the part `- - %in% ids` because R `%in%` compares returns the id if there is a match.

```
getAges <- function(...)
{
   DF[DF$ID %in% ids,]$Age
}
```

The function `getIDs` returns correctly. 
The whole code example

```
library('dplyr')
getIDs <- function(..., by = NULL){
    DF %>% filter_(...) %>% { if (!is.null(by))  arrange_(., by) else . } %>% .$ID
} 
getAges <- function(...)
{
   DF[DF$ID %in% ids,]$Age
}

DF <- structure(list(ID = c(16265L, 16272L, 16273L, 16420L, 16483L, 
16539L, 16773L, 16786L, 16795L, 17052L, 17453L, 18177L, 18184L, 
19088L, 19090L, 19093L, 19140L, 19830L), Age = c(32L, 20L, 28L, 
38L, 42L, 35L, 26L, 32L, 20L, 45L, 32L, 26L, 34L, 41L, 45L, 34L, 
38L, 50L), Gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("female", 
"male"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Age", "Gender"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))

ids <- getIDs(by = "desc(Age)")

ages <- getAges(ids) # TODO this fails

str(ids)
str(ages)
#  int [1:18] 19830 17052 19090 16483 19088 16420 19140 16539 18184 19093 ...
# int [1:18] 32 20 28 38 42 35 26 32 20 45 ... # TODO why here this order?
```

Original data as a list

```
#Original
#ID Age Gender
#16265  32  male
#16272  20  female
#16273  28  female
#16420  38  female
#16483  42  male
#16539  35  female
#16773  26  male
#16786  32  female
#16795  20  female
#17052  45  female
#17453  32  female
#18177  26  female
#18184  34  female
#19088  41  female
#19090  45  male
#19093  34  male
#19140  38  female
#19830  50  female
```

Expected output of `getAges`: list of ages corresponding to the order of the list `ids`

R: 3.3.2
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: What would you consider as a correct result of `getAges`?

Comment: `ids` "tags" all values from DF so the order of `Age` matches that of the original DF.

Comment: btw, your `getAges` function seems a bit vulnerable -- (1) arguments you pass through `...` are not recognized by name and (2) its body consists of accessing global variables, which might lead to working code when there should have been errors. For example, consider `ff = function(...) a + b` and see `ff(a = 2, b = 3)` (assuming you have no "a" and/or "b" in `.GlobalEnv`) or `a = 1; b = 2; ff(a = 150, b = 304)`

Comment: @Masi : You could either make as much as posible explicit (which, apparently does not fit your needs) like a definition of `get = function(data, column_to_search, search_against, column_to_return)` or you might consider adding a class to your workflow like `class(DF) = c("mydf", "data.frame"); getAges = function(x, ...) UseMethod("getAges"); getAges.mydf = function(x, ids = x$id) {}`. Of course, the same can be done without classes less explicitly. I'm not familiar, but maybe other class systems can offer a more explicit `DF.getAges()` scheme.

Comment: @Masi : After a quick playaround with `library(R6)`, here is an interesting approach: `mydataframe = R6Class("mydataframe", 
                      public = list(data = data.frame(ID = integer(), Age = integer(), gender = character()),
                     initialize = function(x) { stopifnot(c("ID", "Age", "Gender") %in% names(x)); self$data = x },
         getIDs = function(..., by = NULL) self$data %>% filter_(...) %>% { if (!is.null(by))  arrange_(., by) else . } %>% .$ID,
         getAges = function(ids = self$data$ID) self$data$Age[match(ids, self$data$ID)]))` (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) And an example use `DF2$getIDs(by = "desc(Age)"); DF2$getAges(); DF2$getAges(DF2$getIDs(by = "desc(Age)"))`. This, indeed, might seem a bit too much to just use "data.frame" operations and, to be honest, I personally would choose something more simple (e.g. S3 or simple functions with few arguments). But (1) it seems close to the approach (I think) you had in mind and (2) its important to organize the workflow in what suits each ones style best. (not sure I can post a concrete answer on this as I'm not familiar and, also, I'd look like crazy if answer so off-topic.. :-))

Comment: (..cont) sorry, forgot to add `DF2 = mydataframe$new(DF)`

Comment: @alexis_laz Please, see the wiki answer below. I think there is one bracket too much at the end. Feel free to add any comments in the code to explain more about it.

Comment: Can you show us what your end goal dataframe looks like? I am thinking you just want to join this table to itself - getting all the other members of the list that have the same age together in one new id 'bundle', no?

Answer (score 2):

If the only purpose of `getAges` is to lookup the ages of `ids` then try

```
getAges <- function(...)
{
   DF[match(ids,DF$ID),"Age"]
}
```

Comment: Confirmed, this works as expected. - - Do you understand why my proposal is actually doing?

Comment: @Masi : With `x = letters[1:5]` compare `x[x %in% c("c", "b")]` which subsets `x` with a "logical" to `x[match(c("c", "b"), x)]` which subsets `x` with an "integer"

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr`

```
getAges <- 
    DF %>% 
    na.omit %>% 
    arrange(desc(Age),ID) %>% 
    select(Age)

getAges
   Age
1   50
2   45
3   45
4   42
5   41
6   38
7   38
8   35
9   34
10  34
11  32
12  32
13  32
14  28
15  26
16  26
17  20
18  20
> as.list(getAges)
$Age
 [1] 50 45 45 42 41 38 38 35 34 34 32 32 32 28 26 26 20 20
```

However, (though here I can only surmise) if you leave your data in a dataframe you will have a much easier time of it in your next step, too.
See [here](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) for a great introduction to that subject or if wideo is your thing, an excellent classic video from an R meetup is [here](https://vimeo.com/33727555). In viewing that it may be helpful to note that we now use his `tidyr` functions which make the melting and recasting in `reshape` even easier, and of course `dplyr` has completely altered the way we do the manipulations to the dataframes: avoiding the base R `$col` and `[]` based referencing.

Comment: I am just thinking if there is any more simpler way to write the function. I find it difficult to maintain codes with much `%>%`. - - Can you please explain the benefits of your method in comparison to ruaridhw's proposal.

Comment: The best reason I can offer can be found starting about 31:25 here: https://vimeo.com/33727555

Comment: The video is about tidy data. So when you use tidy data, you do not need to reconstruct data again and again. Makes sense. If you use just match, it goes to the basic problem right away. - - Can your proposal still be simplified and/or reconstructed?

Comment: Essentially, I am agreeing with how useful it has been for me to think/work at the dataframe level, and best take advantage of vectorised data manipulation capabilities. Like using a cnc sewing machine, versus handstitching.

Answer (score 0):

alexis_laz's proposal of comments for the improvement about `...` in the function

```
library(R6)

DF2 = mydataframe$new(DF)

mydataframe = R6Class("mydataframe", 
  public = list(
    data = data.frame(ID = integer(), 
    Age = integer(), 
    gender = character()
  ), 
  initialize = function(x) { 
    stopifnot(c("ID", "Age", "Gender") %in% names(x)); self$data = x 
  }, 
  getIDs = function(..., by = NULL) self$data %>% filter_(...) %>% { 
    if (!is.null(by)) arrange_(., by) else . 
  } 
  %>% .$ID, 
  getAges = function(ids = self$data$ID) self$data$Age[match(ids, self$data$ID)]
  )#not sure if correct amount
)

# Use by 
DF2$getIDs(by = "desc(Age)"); 
DF2$getAges(); 
DF2$getAges(DF2$getIDs(by = "desc(Age)"))
```